# Reading ByteArrays with SAS

Tags: encoding, sas

I have a file that contains numbers in ByteArrays written in Java or Python. How do I read them in with SAS? I am new to SAS and don't know where to start.

Comment: It will help to include a sample of the data you are asking to read in SAS.

Comment: Read them for what? What are you looking to do with it?

Comment: SAS has some formats for converting bytes to numbers, but it depends on the format:  Floating point or integer, how many bits, signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 0):

The word byte array doesn't help much. I could say almost everything is an array of bytes. In C#, you can simply state an array of bytes:

```
byte[] myData = new[] {0, 1, 2 ,3};
```

To read in SAS, here is some general code but you will need to determine the specifics based upon your needs (just play around until you get the code correct):

```
data test;
   infile 'c:\temp\myDataFile.txt';
   input myByteData 4. ;
run;
```

That '4.' is the key. It is called an informat. Depending upon how you want to interpret the bytes, you can specify a numeric, a character, or something else. SAS onl understands strings and doubles but can read in anything. Just play with the informat type and length until you get your data in the way you like.

You can also ignore the length and leave it blank (numeric) or use a single $ for strings. SAS will try and figure it out for you.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning the `pib.` and `rb.` informats here.